# mysqli does not execute Select statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have the code bellow. When I use this code without the `WHERE` clause, all the users from the table are displayed, as expected. But when the `WHERE` clause is used, nothing is displayed.

What could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

```
function requestUser($user) {
  $DBHost   = "localhost";
  $DBUser   = "dbUser";
  $DBPass   = "dbPass";
  $DBName   = "dbName";

  $db = new mysqli($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
  if ($db -> connect_errno > 0) { 
    $lbOK = false; 
  }
  else {
    $lbOK = $db -> set_charset('utf8');
  } 

  if ($lbOK) {
    $id         = NULL;
    $user_name  = NULL;
    $user       = htmlentities($user, ENT_QUOTES);
    $lcSQL      = "SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE user_name=?";
    $stmt       = $db -> prepare($lcSQL);
    $ok         = $stmt -> bind_param('s', $user);
    $ok         = $stmt -> execute();
    $ok         = $stmt -> bind_result($user_name);

    while ($row = $stmt -> fetch()){
      echo $user_name;
    }

    $stmt->close();
  }
}
```

Comment: May be no one matched with where clause !

Comment: Are you sure you have users with the user_name '?'?

Comment: Yes, there are users that match the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many major faults with your code, some of them can be responsible for the problem, and some not. But nevertheless, they all have to be corrected

1. **Never** connect co database inside of an application function. Connect somewhere in the bootstrap file, once, and use that single connection throughout all the application.
2. Do not use htmlentities with whatever database interactions. It may easily spoil the data
3. Always check for the the errors
4. Do not use mysqli, it is unusable. Use PDO instead.

   ```
   $dsn = "mysql:host=DBHost;dbname=DBName;charset=utf8";
   $opt = array(
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
   );
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$DBUser, $DBPass, $opt);

   function requestUser($user) {
     global $db;

     $sql  = "SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE user_name=?";
     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute(array($user));
     return $stmt->fetchColumn();
   }
   echo requestUser($user);
   ```

if it still doesn't work, verify it this way

```
  $sql  = "SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE user_name='$user'";
  var_dump($sql);
```

and then try to run in console/phpmyadmin to find out what's wrong with your data/value

Comment: Thank you for your hints. The function I've posted is just for testing. In my application the DB connection is established in the bootstrap. The code you gave me uses PDO methods and I cannot use PDO because it is not available on the server... And cannot change that...

Comment: There are users in the DB that match the WHERE clause.

Comment: I've just tested my code on a server with MySQL 5+ and it is working. On the server I have to make this work there is MySQL 4.1.22 (above 4.1 as stated in the phpManual). Could this be a cause?

Comment: no. you need to test your code on the server with actual data.

Comment: Done! I've recreated the DB on both servers. On the one with MySQL 5+ it works, on the other one it doesn't.

Comment: @LucianIlea mind item 3 in my list. mysqli_error is what you need desperately. And if it turned to be that 4.1 doesn't support prepared statements, PDO or [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) will be your only choice

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to convince the server administrator to install the PDO extension. Using PDO everything works perfect! Thanks again for your ideas!

Comment: yup. PDO have a fallback in case of native prepared not working